# Set auto_increment value to each unique group

Tags: mysql, group-by, auto-increment

I've got a MySQL innodb [table (sqlfiddle demo)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ad82/1) with

> `id`, `name_id`, `name`, `content`

And content like

```
1, NULL, 'Brian', 'Bridge to terabithia'
2, NULL, 'Brian', 'Pulp fiction'
3, NULL, 'Brian', 'Trainspotting'
4, NULL, 'Luke', 'Watchmen'
5, NULL, 'Luke', 'Constantine'
6, NULL, 'Tony', 'Dark knight'
7, NULL, 'Tony', 'Shutter Island'
8, NULL, 'John', 'Machinist'
9, NULL, 'John', 'Matrix'
10, NULL, 'John', 'Sin city'
11, NULL, 'John', 'Mad Max'
```

The `id` is unique to each row. But I can't get, how to set auto_increment `name_id` to each unique name.

[Here's (sqlfiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/839f9/1) what I'm trying to achieve.

```
1, 1, 'Brian', 'Bridge to terabithia'
2, 1, 'Brian', 'Pulp fiction'
3, 1, 'Brian', 'Trainspotting'
4, 2, 'Luke', 'Watchmen'
5, 2, 'Luke', 'Constantine'
6, 3, 'Tony', 'Dark knight'
7, 3, 'Tony', 'Shutter Island'
8, 4, 'John', 'Machinist'
9, 4, 'John', 'Matrix'
10, 4, 'John', 'Sin city'
11, 4, 'John', 'Mad Max'
```

Is it possible to do with MySQL only?
Thank you for reading.

Comment: That's not what `auto_increment` does, or even how it should be used...

Comment: I think it is better to make a different table for the names if you want to give every name an unique id, look at this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cc60/6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is you can't do this automatically with only `auto_increment`, and you probably shouldn't either.

If really have reason to do this you would be much better off normalizing your database, creating a "names" table (name_id PK, name) and removing the "name" column from this table. Honestly I'm not sure what you can really gain from doing this in your example, but I imagine it might be an abstraction of the problem.